# Can't boot into latest kernel after update - volume group not found / cannot process volume group

Tags: boot, lvm

Last week I updated my laptop running Debian Buster, and I got a warning but didn't take proper notice and now after restarting, it won't boot into the kernel 4.19.0.8, but it works with 4.19.0.6. The disk is encrypted with Luks/LVM.

At boot, I see messages like this:

```
mnc0: unknown controller version (3)
volume group vg-abc not found
cannot process volume group vg-abc
```

After a while it boots into initramfs.

Laptop: Dell Lattitude E7240

How can I fix this boot problem?

---

Update, as requested, lshw output

```
impala
    description: Laptop
    product: Latitude E7240 (05CA)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: 00
    serial: *****
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=laptop frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=05CA uuid=*************************
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 05PTPV
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /********/*************/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A18
          date: 04/28/2016
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 12MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 42
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 3224MHz
          capacity: 3300MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 43
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 44
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 45
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 4MiB
             capacity: 4MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 46
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: HP16D3LS1KFG/4G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: ********
             slot: DIMM A
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: HP16D3LS1KFG/4G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: *********
             slot: DIMM B
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:49 memory:f7e34000-f7e37fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series USB xHCI HC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7e20000-f7e2ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=9 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Video
                   product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
                   vendor: CN07YYTT7248748MACT1A00
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@2:4
                   version: 35.06
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 4.19
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series HECI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:47 memory:f7e3f000-f7e3f01f
        *-communication:1
             description: Serial controller
             product: 8 Series HECI KT
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.3
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm msi 16550 cap_list
             configuration: driver=serial latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:f0e0(size=8) memory:f7e3d000-f7e3dfff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 04
             serial: ******************
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.6-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:42 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e3c000-f7e3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:f7e30000-f7e33fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 73
                serial: *******************
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.19.0-6-amd64 firmware=17.3216344376.0 ip=192.168.178.29 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:48 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-generic
                description: SD Host controller
                product: SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
                vendor: O2 Micro, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:44 memory:f7c01000-f7c01fff memory:f7c00000-f7c007ff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:21 memory:f7e3b000-f7e3b3ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb UNCLAIMED
                      description: Generic USB device
                      product: 5880
                      vendor: Broadcom Corp
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@1:1.5
                      version: 1.01
                      serial: 0123456789ABCD
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 8 Series LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-raid
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi1
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: raid msi pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:43 ioport:f0d0(size=8) ioport:f0c0(size=4) ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7e3a000-f7e3a7ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: SAMSUNG SSD SM84
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 4D6Q
                serial: **************
                size: 238GiB (256GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=e7581358-ab20-4b16-a0c4-fdd04a82dd96 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: **********
                   size: 510MiB
                   capacity: 511MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
              *-volume:1
                   description: EFI partition
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /boot
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: ****************************
                   size: 244MiB
                   capabilities: extended_attributes large_files ext2 initialized
                   configuration: filesystem=ext2 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2020-03-02 21:24:02 mount.fstype=ext2 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2020-03-02 21:24:02 state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: EFI partition
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   serial: ******************************
                   size: 237GiB
                   capacity: 237GiB
                   width: 3907713352 bits
                   capabilities: encrypted luks initialized
                   configuration: bits=8202680648 filesystem=luks hash=sha256 version=2
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7e39000-f7e390ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device DLL05ca
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 aux
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0401
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:09
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: a
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
  *-battery
       product: DELL P8TC727
       vendor: Samsung SDI
       physical id: 1
       version: 12/20/2018
       serial: ****
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 23680mWh
       configuration: voltage=7.4V
```

Comment: It would help if you would specify your laptop and do a `lshw` for us.

Comment: Are the GRUB entries the same, just with a different kernel file? can you boot into 4.19.0.6 and re-install the update to see what is the warning message?

Comment: @tukan, I've updated the question, but I don't see how the hardware specs matter.

Comment: @golimar, I've booted into 4.19.0.6 and did an update, but only libcrypt1 was updated. Which grub entries should I look at?

Comment: There should be a "menuentry" section in grub.cfg for each of the options that GRUB shows up on boot, so there should be entries for the old and new kernels, you can compare both to see what has changed. Or alternatively reinstall the package of the new kernel (it will not show up in updates, but you can reinstall installed packages)

Comment: I checked your configuration.  Do you have the AHCI or RAID configuration in BIOS?  You could also try making a diff from your kernel .cfg files to see what are the differences.

Comment: Blacklist the mmc ? https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1289981

Comment: Try to update the initramfs for 4.19.0.8. It seems that the appropriate module is not included in your initramfs for some reason (may be this was the warning that you got). Run `update-initramfs -u -k 4.19.0.8` (check the full tag of the kernel version).

Comment: I messed up the installation while trying to find a solution, then had to reinstall to 10.3 instead of 10.2 and that went OK with the lastest kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's face the facts:

Debian is known to be stable and that's why I am on Debian, as well.

But let's face it, it comes with serious errors from time to time and those are hard to track down. If it works with the previous Kernel, consider it a bug! Really!

I had such problems now and then. Never was there a reason or it took weeks before the first bug-tracker had the first entries with explanation.

Debian is far away from being perfect, so just stay with the old kernel and check from time to time via web search or try after the next update of the said components.